# How to type negative number with .isdigit?

Tags: python

when I try this

```
if question.isdigit() is True:
```

I can type in numbers fine, and this would filter out alpha/alphanumeric strings

when I try 's1' and 's' for example, it would go to (else).

Problem is, when I put negative number such as -1, '.isdigit' counts '-' sign as string value and it rejects it. How can I make it so that '.isdigit' allows negative symbol '-'?

Here is the code. Of the thing i tried.

```
while a <=10 + Z:
    question = input("What is " + str(n1) + str(op) + str(n2) + "?")
    a = a+1

    if question.lstrip("-").isdigit() is True:
        ans = ops[op](n1, n2)
        n1 = random.randint(1,9)
        n2 = random.randint(1,9)
        op = random.choice(list(ops))

        if int(question) is ans:
            count = count + 1
            Z = Z + 0
            print ("Well done")
        else:
            count = count + 0
            Z = Z + 0
            print ("WRONG")
    else:
        count = count + 0
        Z = Z + 1
        print ("Please type in the number")
```

Comment: Please provide 1) sampel input, 2) the output for each input value.

Comment: what is wrong with: https://www.kite.com/python/answers/how-to-check-if-a-string-represents-an-integer-in-python#:~:text=To%20check%20for%20positive%20integers,rest%20must%20represent%20an%20integer.?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Use a try/except, if we cannot cast to an int it will set `is_dig` to `False`:

```
try:
    int(question)
    is_dig = True
except ValueError:
    is_dig = False
if is_dig:
  ......
```

Or make a function:

```
def is_digit(n):
    try:
        int(n)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return  False

if is_digit(question):
   ....
```

Looking at your edit cast to int at the start,checking if the input is a digit and then casting is pointless, do it in one step:

```
while a < 10: 
     try:
        question = int(input("What is {} {} {} ?".format(n1,op,n2)))
     except ValueError:
        print("Invalid input")
        continue # if we are here we ask user for input again

    ans = ops[op](n1, n2)
    n1 = random.randint(1,9)
    n2 = random.randint(1,9)
    op = random.choice(list(ops))

    if question ==  ans:
        print ("Well done")
    else:
        print("Wrong answer")
    a += 1
```

Not sure what Z is doing at all but  `Z = Z + 0` is the same as not doing anything to `Z` at all `1 + 0 == 1`

Using a function to take the input we can just use range:

```
def is_digit(n1,op,n2):
    while True:
        try:
            n = int(input("What is {} {} {} ?".format(n1,op,n2)))
            return n
        except ValueError:
            print("Invalid input")


for _ in range(a):
    question = is_digit(n1,op,n2) # will only return a value when we get legal input
    ans = ops[op](n1, n2)
    n1 = random.randint(1,9)
    n2 = random.randint(1,9)
    op = random.choice(list(ops))

    if question ==  ans:
        print ("Well done")
    else:
        print("Wrong answer")
```

Answer (score 85):

Use `lstrip`:

```
question.lstrip("-").isdigit()
```

Example:

```
>>>'-6'.lstrip('-')
'6'
>>>'-6'.lstrip('-').isdigit()
True
```

You can `lstrip('+-')` if you want to consider `+6` a valid digit.

But I wouldn't use `isdigit`, you can try `int(question)`, it'll throw an exception if the value cannot be represented as `int`:

```
try:
    int(question)
except ValueError:
    # not int
```

Comment: try...except takes a long time

Comment: @Wdoctor123 it removes `-` sign, leaving you with 1.

Comment: i tied it with my code and it works! when the question askes what is 1-4, i put -3 and it says it is correct. however, you said it gets rid of    -    sign so how does it even work? if you get rid of - sign, surely system would read it as 3 instead of -3

Comment: @Wdoctor123 it'll strip only the leftmost sign, `3-4` won't be affected.

Comment: 3-4? and what is leftmost sign? sorry, i'm new to python X

Comment: @Wdoctor123 `'3-4'.lstrip('-')` will return `3-4`, but `'-5'.lstrip('-')` will return 5. In `3-4` the leftmost digit is 3, and since you're stripping according to `-`, nothing will happen.

Comment: by the way, question = answer to the question. its a variable. Just in case you miss interpreted is

Comment: question.lstrip('-') = '-3'.lstrip('-') in my case.

Comment: Be careful that '-------123' will also be valid with this solution. If you know this won't happen then this is the shortest approach.

Answer (score 6):

If you do not wish to go for try... except, you could use regular expression

```
if re.match("[+-]?\d", question) is not None:
    question = int(question)
else:
    print "Not a valid number"
```

With try... except, it is simpler:

```
try:
    question = int(question)
except ValueError:
    print "Not a valid number"
```

If isdigit is must and you need to preserve the original value as well, you can either use lstrip as mentioned in an answer given. Another solution will be:

```
if question[0]=="-":
    if question[1:].isdigit():
        print "Number"
else:
    if question.isdigit():
        print "Number"
```

Answer (score 0):

I have just had a similar question on edabit where I realised that negative numbers returned as False whilst using isnumeric(). I have put my solution below:
Create a function that takes a list of strings and integers, and filters out the list so that it returns a list of integers only.

```
def filter_list(list):
    numbers = [i for i in list if str(i).isnumeric() == True]
    for i in list:
        try:
            int(i)
            if i <0:
                numbers.append(i)
        except ValueError:
            continue
    return numbers
list = [1,2,3,'a','b','c', -6, 0]
print(filter_list(list))
```

I am still new to Python so this is a basic attempt. Feel free to let me know if there is a much easier or better looking way.

Answer (score 0):

To check if your input string is numeric or not, even in cases when you enter negative values or floats you can do this:

```
if string.replace('.','').replace('-','').isnumeric():
    print(string + ' is a number')
```

If you want to check specifically if your string is a negative number you can do this:

```
if string[0] == '-' and string[1:].replace('.','').isnumeric():
    print(string + ' is a negative number')
```

Edit: Replace removes all "." and "-" from the string, so "...-1-.-" would classify as a number too!

Answer (score 0):

I know it's late, but I just stumbled appon this question and I had a similar problem wich I solved this way:

```
@staticmethod
    def getStringToFloatOrNone(value):
        if value == None:
            return None  
        if not str(value).replace(",","").replace(".","").replace("-","").strip().isdigit(): 
            return 0   
        return value if isinstance(value, float) or isinstance(value, int) else float(Helper.createViableFloatOrIntString(value))  

        return int(float(value)) if isinstance(value, float) or isinstance(value, int) else int(float(Helper.createViableFloatOrIntString(value)))
```

Just replace all the common delimitter and try if it's a digit.
If yes, get the actual value as float.

Answer (score 0):

Simple way to do this using lambda,

```
is_numeric = lambda x: x.replace('.', '', 1).replace('-', '', 1).isdigit()
```

You can use this like:

```
if is_numeric(question):
    ## your code here ##
```

@Hurri have done something similar, but afraid it return **True** for values like IP addresses.