# Strange output with isdigit ()

Tags: python, python-3.7

I`ve got a problem: when I "input" something like -10 or -200, and I check it for isdigit(), it will write False. And a strangest thing that, if I write int(number) (int(-10) works too!) programm will print number. Without raising any exceptions.

```
number = input()
res = number.isdigit()
print(res)
print(int(number))

#number: -10, res: False
#number: 200, res: True

#number: -10, output: -10
#number: 200, output: 200
```

Can you help me? Thanks in advance!

Comment: `isDigit` is looking at the minus sign, and sees that it is not a numerical digit.

Comment: `isdigit` does exactly what its name implies:  It checks for a digit.  `0`-`9` are digits.  `-` is not a digit.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to type negative number with .isdigit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28279732/how-to-type-negative-number-with-isdigit)

Answer (score 1):

The isdigit() method returns True if all characters in a string are digits. If not, it returns False. The minus sign is not accounted as a digit.