# Take integer only from a nested list and apply function to it

Tags: python

I am super new at Python and I am facing a problem when converting a nested list to a list of integer only.

I have this type of nested list in which all sub-list contains strings (digit and char)

```
lists = [['1', '2', '0', 'a', 'b'], ['3', '2', '1'], ['1','5', '5']]
```

I want to convert the digits to integer, and also put the char in one list. The output that I want is something like this

```
`new_lists = [[1, 2, 0, 'a', 'b'], [3, 2, 1], [1, 5, 5]]`
```

What would i do is something like this

```
for item in lists:
new_list=[]
if (in the first list item can be converted to integer):
    new_list.append(int(item))
else:
  new_list.append(item)
```

How the string can be converted to an integer? Or is there any better way to do it?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Use the isdigit function

Comment: @NirO Unfortunately `isdigit` won't work with negative integers.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28279732/how-to-type-negative-number-with-isdigit

Comment: @NirO The accepted answer for that question basically says not to use `.isdigit()`.

Comment: @Selcuk if you take a look at one answer below, you can see a suggestion to use isdigit together with lstrip. I find it to be suitable solution for your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using `str.isdigit()` you can check whether a string is integer for not.

```
lists2 = list(map(lambda y:[int(x) if x.isdigit() else x for x in y], lists))
```

or

```
list2 = []
for i in lists:
    tmp = []
    for j in i:
         try:
             val = int(j)
         except ValueError:
             val = j
         tmp.append(val)

    list2.append(tmp)
```

Comment: Note that this won't work with negative integers, e.g. `"-1"`.

Answer (score 3):

Define a function that will convert a string to an int when it can, and use it in a nested list comprehension:

```
def safe_int(s):
    try:
        return int(s)
    except ValueError:
        return s

lists = [['1', '2', '0', 'a', 'b'], ['3', '2', '1'], ['1', '5', '5']]
new_lists = [[safe_int(i) for i in sub_list] for sub_list in lists]
```

The value of `new_lists` will be:

```
[[1, 2, 0, 'a', 'b'], [3, 2, 1], [1, 5, 5]]
```

Comment: To decrease cost of `safe_int`, you can actually use `str.isdigit()` insead of a try/except block. [Ref](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/design.html#how-fast-are-exceptions)

Comment: @crissal It won't work for negative integers, and this method can also be extended to other numeric types such as floats.