# list comprehension always returns empty list

Tags: python

making a function that recieves numbers separated by spaces and adds the first element to the rest, the ouput should be a list of numbers if the first element is a number
i'm trying to remove all non numeric elements of list b

examples- input: 1 2 3 4
output: [3, 4, 5] (2+1, 3+1, 4+1)

input: 1 2 b 4
output: [3, 5] (2+1,b is purged, 4+1)

input: a 1 2 3
output: Sucessor invalido

```
linha = input()
a = linha.split()
b = [x for x in (a[1:]) if type(x)==int] 
b = [eval(x) for x in b]
c = eval(a[0])
d = []
d.append(c)
f = d*len(b)
def soma(): 
  if type(c)!= int: return print("Sucessor invalido")
  else: return list(map(lambda x, y: x + y, b, f))
g = soma()
g
```

> > this condition always returns an empty list
>
> ```
> if type(x)==int
> ```

sorry if im not clear, i started learning recently

Comment: The return value of `print` is `None`.  What are you trying to accomplish? What is the input?

Comment: `input` returns a string. Nothing in that string will be an int. Also -- there is no need to use `eval` to convert a numerical string to an int. `int` is perfectly capable.

Answer (score 2):

Two things:

1. The results of `input` are always strings. When you split the string, you end up with more strings. So even if that string is `'7'`, it is the string 7, not the integer 7.
2. If you want to check if an object is of a type, use `isinstance(x,int)` rather than `type(x)==int`.

To accomplish what it looks like you are doing, I dunno if you can get it with list comprehension, since you probably want a `try:...except:...` block, like this.

```py
linha = input()
a = linha.split()
b = [] #empty list
for x in a[1:]: # confusing thing you are doing here, also... you want to skip the first element?
    try:
        x_int = int(x)
        b.append(x_int)
    except ValueError:
        pass
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the numbers separated by lines to integers, after checking that they are valid numberic values like this:

```
b = [int(x) for x in (a[1:]) if x.isnumeric()]
```

this is because your input will be a string by default, and `split()` will be just a list of strings

Comment: thank you, this solved the problem but now its excluding negative numbers now

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28279732/how-to-type-negative-number-with-isdigit might be your friend

Answer (score 0):

Your input is `string`, you need to cast it to `int` and then do calculation to append it to a new list.

The function should check for the index 0 first using `str.islpha()` method. If it's an alphabet, return invalid input.

Use try except when iterating the input list. If some element can't be cast to int it will continue to the next index.

```
def soma(linha):
    if linha[0].isalpha():
        return f"Sucessor invalido"
    result = []
    for i in range(len(linha) - 1):
        try:
            result.append(int(linha[0]) + int(linha[i+1]))
        except ValueError:
            continue
    return result


linha = input().split()

print(soma(linha))
```

Output:

```
1 2 3 4
[3, 4, 5]

1 2 b 4
[3, 5]

a 1 2 3
Sucessor invalido
```