# MYSQL INSERT looping through columns and values from dict

Tags: python, mysql

I am trying to insert records into MySQL and running into a few issues.

Data is in dict format with exact column names from the table as key, values are a mix of either strings or ints.

```py
def db_insert(table, **data):
    cursor = db.cursor()
    columns = data.keys()
    columns_str = ', '.join(columns)
    values = []
    for i in columns:
        value = data[i]
        if value.isdigit() is True:
            values.append("'s%'")
        else:
            value.append('s%')
    # convert list to string for SQL statement
    value_holder = ', '.join(values)

    sql = "INSERT INTO {table} ({columns_str}) VALUES ({value_holder})".format(table=table, columns_str=columns_str,
                                                                               value_holder=value_holder)

    # ensure column values are assigned to correct column names by using loop, just pulling values doesnt ensure order
    value_list = []
    for i in columns:
        value = data[i]
        value_list.append(value)
    # print(sql, value_list)
    value_list_str = ', '.join(value_list)
    cursor.execute(sql, value_list_str)
    db.commit()
    # obtain and return new record PK id
    new_id = cursor.lastrowid
    cursor.close()
    return new_id

db_insert('table', **dict_data)
```

Currently I am getting an error showing `value.isdigit() is True`

> attributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'isdigit'.

I read from other entries that the s% for SQL needs to be 's%' if its an integer, which is why I am looping through the values to determine if it is an integer and adding either s% or 's%'.

Comment: I don't work with SQL, but will `value = str(data[i])` solve your problem? That'll convert the value to a string, so it's not an `int`, so you can use `isdigit`.

Comment: Alternatively, if you want to keep the int an int, you could try `if isinstance(value, int) or value.isdigit():`, which will short circuit if the value is an `int`, preventing the error you received.

Comment: Might your values be negative? `isdigit` doesn't work with strings of negative values, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28279732/how-to-type-negative-number-with-isdigit).

Comment: Do you mean old fashioned %s or really s% ?

Comment: Thanks for the pointers everyone. There were no negative numbers in the data, as Hermann12 pointed out I replaced the s% with %s as well as converting the list of values into a tuple before passing to cursor.execute. This resolved  the int issue but now I get an error: _mysql_connector.MySQLInterfaceError: Python type list cannot be converted. As this looks to be a MySQL connector issue, is the problem with the SQL statement itself or possibly how it is being processed by the connector?

Comment: This sounds like a completely different question, so you should make a completely different post or just completely change this post if you no longer have the original problem. You should also show the entire stack trace.

Comment: Comment this line `value_list_str = ', '.join(value_list)` you don´t need it and change the cursor execute to `cursor.execute(sql, value_list)` You don´t need to send a string, you can send a list of values

Comment: thanks everyone, some of the data from the json file was being returned in a tuple form which caused the second error.