# Python Nested lambda function

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list, lambda

Would there be a way to write a nested lambda function? The following is what I am trying to do:

```
s = '123 there'
f = lambda x: x.split()
g = lambda x: [int(x[0]), x[1]]

#g(f(s)) returns [123, 'there']
```

However, I want to merge these two lambda functions together.

Comment: Why? Lambda functions aren't designed to be named functions. They are supposed to be used and not remembered. Why not just use a `def`? What is the goal here? Besides, what happens if `x.split()[0]` does not convert to an int or `x.split()` does not contain 2 elements?

Comment: what do you mean by "nested lambda function"?  What exactly are you trying to do? what do you mean by "merge"? do you just want `h = lambda s: g(f(s))`?

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend not using lambda functions unless your use case is suited to them. As the comments suggest, just use a `def` function!

However, you can do the following to nest your lambda functions.

```
f = lambda s: (x := s.split(), [int(x[0]), x[1]])[1]
```

---

```
>>> f('123 result')
[123, 'result']
```

Answer (score 2):

I really, really, really don't recommend doing this.  As others have said, this isn't what lambda functions are for.  But A J Uppal above has given you one hack for getting what you want.  Here's another:

```
lambda s, f=(lambda x: x.split()), g=(lambda x: [int(x[0]), x[1]]): g(f(s))
```

I think this makes your intent a little bit clearer.  There are all sorts of ways of abusing optional arguments in lambdas.

But again, don't do it.

Comment: For theoretical purposes only... I like this! Gets the composite function across :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do without lambda with list comprehension:

```
s = '-123 there'

[int(x) if x.lstrip("-").isnumeric() else x for x in s.split() ]

#[-123, 'there']
```

---

```
s = '123 there'

[int(x) if x.lstrip("-").isnumeric() else x for x in s.split() ]

#[123, 'there']
```

Comment: `.isdigit()` is not equivalent to what can be achieved by `int()`. Check negative numbers for example.

Comment: What @S.B is saying is if `s = '-123 there` then your list comprehension would return `['-123', 'there']` since `'-123'.isdigit()` is False.

Comment: `def try_int(x): try: return int(x) except ValueError: return x` then you use that in the loop

Comment: here is an example to check negative numbers with isdigit https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28279732/how-to-type-negative-number-with-isdigit

Comment: If you are like me and wrote something similar but using `.isnumeric()` rather than `.isdigit()` and wondered what the difference was, check out [What's the difference between str.isdigit(), isnumeric() and isdecimal() in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44891070/whats-the-difference-between-str-isdigit-isnumeric-and-isdecimal-in-pyth)

Comment: yes I was thinking about `isnumeric` I will update. Thanks Jon:)

Answer (score 0):

I do not suggest using lambdas for something like this. Reasons being: You made a lambda for a single function. This makes no sense. Also what happens if after you split the string and there aren't 2 elements or the first element cannot be converted to an int and throws an error.

What you could do is make an actual function that does the logic and error handling, then use that on the string:

```
def try_int(x):
    try:
        return int(x) 
    except ValueError:
        return x

[try_int(x) for x in s]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your idea of "nesting" remains unclear.

If you want a new function `h` that behaves like `h(x) == g(f(x))`, then you can do this:

```
h = lambda x: g(f(x))
```

If you want a single expression not relying on definitions of `f` and `g`... you can simulate variable assignment using an inner lambda that is executed immediately.

```
h = lambda x: (lambda y: [int(y[0]), y[1]])(x.split())
```

[Frank Yellin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77419117) has a certain appeal because it maintains the definitions of `f` and `g` but pulls them into the definition of `h` itself.

Still, all of this is fairly convoluted and better expressed *without* lambdas.